# how do we translate 不肝不氪 in games？ no hardness no charge?

Tags: translation, games

how do we translate 不肝不氪 in game-term？
肝in terms of being hard to play or needing so much time to complete,
氪represent 氪金 means to spend money。
so this phrase basically means a game is easy to play with, with no need to spend too many times, and doesn't requires an extra charge or payment to complete the whole game experience
we tried to directly translate in: no hardness no charge. but it didn't have the correct feel.
since 肝 is the liver which is a type of internal organ.
In Chinese perception, if you often stay up late, it will affect the health of your liver
Therefore, the liver here represents those who need to stay up all night in order to play games.
obviously, the simple word "hardness" didn't have the same feeling.

Answer (score 3):

- 不肝 = no-grinding
- 不氪 = no-microtransactions (-or- no-pay-to-win)

---

肝 is short for staying up late. It's usually used as a synonym for *[grinding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grinding_(video_games))*:

> repeating an action or set of actions, including non-repetitive tasks to achieve a desired result at a level of certain difficulty, typically for an extended period of time

The opposite is 金 or 氪金. The best English equivalent would be [Microtransaction(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microtransaction):

> Microtransactions, sometimes abbreviated as mtx, are a business model where users can purchase virtual goods with micropayments within a game. Microtransactions are often used in free-to-play games to provide a revenue source for the developers. While microtransactions are a staple of the mobile app market, they are also seen on PC software such as Valve's Steam digital distribution platform, as well as console gaming.

Answer (score 1):

How about "casual and free?"

Answer (score 1):

I found this explanation:

这个词大部分情况下是形容一款游戏的，首先可以把这四个字分开来分析分，分成两部分，肝的意思就是每天花大量的时间来玩这个游戏，才能把这个游戏给它玩好，当然不肝就是不用花费大量的时间去投入到游戏当中；氪的意思就是氪金，就是游戏中所谓的人民币玩家，往游戏里大量的充钱，当然不氪就是不需要大量人民币也能玩的好的游戏。

不肝不氪的意思：a game which won't cost you much time or money to play well.